# Python and XPath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xmpp

I'm trying to parse [this XML](http://pastebin.com/d2b611t3)

I want to get a list of all of the mechanisms, so I'm trying to use XPATH (please suggest if theres an easier way) to get the mechanisms...

Here is my code:

```
parseMessage = libxml2.parseDoc(doc)
xpathcon = parseMessage.xpathNewContext()

xpathcon.xpathRegisterNs('urn','http://etherx.jabber.org/streams')
nodes = xpathcon.xpathEval("//urn:text()")
print nodes
```

And here is the error I'm getting...

```
Entity: line 1: parser error : Premature end of data in tag stream line 1 
h"/><register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register"/></stream:features>
```

I know that my code doesn't remove all the mechanisms but first I'd just like to get around the issue at hand. Anyway to make this into correct XML that can be parsed? Do I need to add a new header or remove a header or do something else?

Comment: Why not use an existing XMPP library?

Comment: The XML you linked to is missing a closing `</stream:stream>`. You need to fix whatever is emitting that XML first.

Comment: @millimoose no, that's completly normal for an XMPP server.

Comment: Can I just add the "</stream:stream>" ?

Comment: @Zash Oh, XMPP doesn't work by streaming well-formed documents? Odd. My bad then.

Comment: @Dan If you know that's all the XML you have to process, and the missing closing tag is a known XMPPism, then it should be fine to just close the tag.

Comment: Adding the missing tag is always wrong.  To learn more about XMPP, see: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6120

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please** use one of the [existing XMPP libraries](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).

Next: you're not going to be successful with XMPP thinking of it like a document.  You'll be able to hack around it for a few days making yourself believe that you're on to something, and then you'll realize that there is no way to tell when the server is done sending you information, so there's no way to know when to call what you have a document.

Instead, use a stream-based parser.  [SleekXMPP](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP) uses [xml.etree.cElementTree.iterparse](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) with a wrapper around the socket to make it smell like a file.  There are likely other ways, like using [xml.parsers.expat](http://docs.python.org/library/pyexpat.html) directly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to build an XMPP library.  Why not use [an existing library](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/), such as [SleekXMPP](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP)?

If you *really* need to build your own XMPP library, you'll need to use [a streaming parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML), such as [Expat](http://docs.python.org/library/pyexpat).